# golang and neo4j using golang-neo4j-bolt-driver

Tags: go, neo4j

I'm trying out the golang-neo4j-bolt-driver package
[github.com/johnnadratowski/golang-neo4j-bolt-driver](http://github.com/johnnadratowski/golang-neo4j-bolt-driver)

I have imported the package and am using the example way of creating a new driver:

```
driver := bolt.NewDriver()
```

i get the following:

```
./neo.go:5: imported and not used: "github.com/johnnadratowski/golang-neo4j-bolt-driver" as golangNeo4jBoltDriver
./neo.go:34: undefined: bolt in bolt.NewDriver
```

any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to alias the name of the library

```
bolt "github.com/johnnadratowski/golang-neo4j-bolt-driver"
```

You can see this in their [code examples](https://github.com/johnnadratowski/golang-neo4j-bolt-driver/blob/master/examples/quick_n_dirty/quick_n_dirty.go#L6)